# Laravel error - QueryException in Connection.php line 729:

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

Receiving this error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 729:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`projects`, CONSTRAINT `projects_am_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`am_id`) REFERENCES `employees` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `projects` (`company`, `stage`, `status`, `jira`, `notes`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Test, Waiting for Launch, In Progress, https://www.test.com, Testing, 2017-03-02 14:46:47, 2017-03-02 14:46:47))
```

**Projects Table**
id
company
am_id
etc etc

**Employees Table**
id
name
department

I have the values in the other table so not sure why it can't reference them. Any ideas?

Comment: The am_id value is required when creating records in the projects table, which references an id from the employee table.

Comment: Hi aynber, I am passing a value for it. Here is the model array being created: at Model::create(array('_token' => 'HJX10G7fdhXsZSRFLlfqFWJ4SEsXyEvQh7p41P57', 'company' => 'Test', 'stage' => 'Waiting for Launch', 'status' => 'In Progress', 'date' => '2017-03-02', 'sa' => '7', 'am' => '10', 'pm' => '11', 'sales' => '12', 'jira' => 'https://www.test.com', 'notes' => 'Testing', 'submit' => 'Submit')) in ProjectController.php line 118

Comment: You have `am`, but not `am_id`.

Comment: Do my input names have to be the exact same as the fields in the database?

Comment: Yes, or else it won't know how to match the columns.

Comment: Ah ok. Let me change that and try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you save your project Model, make sure the am_id is filled in.

Now you're trying to save a Project model without the am_id filled in => foreign key error

Comment: Hi, I do have it filled. Here is the model array: at Model::create(array('_token' => 'HJX10G7fdhXsZSRFLlfqFWJ4SEsXyEvQh7p41P57', 'company' => 'Test', 'stage' => 'Waiting for Launch', 'status' => 'In Progress', 'date' => '2017-03-02', 'sa' => '7', 'am' => '10', 'pm' => '11', 'sales' => '12', 'jira' => 'https://www.test.com', 'notes' => 'Testing', 'submit' => 'Submit')) in ProjectController.php line 118

Comment: In your database,  how is the column called? 'am' or 'am_id'?

Comment: In the database, the field is 'am_id'

Comment: they have to match :) So in your html just change the name of the input field to am_id